# Typescript errors with React Native and ContextApi

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to make a react context called Api with some functions responsible for signing in and so on. I copied some code from a project I work on, but that project is plain js and react. I want to implement it on React Native with Typescript. There is the code:

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import Api, { useApi } from './src/context/Api'
import Test from './src/components/Test'

const App: () => React.ReactNode = () => {
    const api = useApi()

    return (
        <Api.Provider value={api}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Test />
            </SafeAreaView>
        </Api.Provider>
    )
}

export default App
```

ApiContext:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import Api from '../helper/Api'

export function useApi() {
    const [api] = useState(new Api())

    return api
}

const ApiContext = createContext(Api)

export default ApiContext
```

ApiHelper class:

```
export interface IApi {
    token: string
    login: Function
}

export default class ApiHelper implements IApi {
    token: string

    constructor() {
        this.token = 'foo'
    }

    login(): boolean {
        this.token = 'bar'
        return true
    }
}
```

Everything works, but I get Typescript errors. First, I have an error in App.tsx on line 10 on value:

```
Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'ApiHelper' but required in type 'typeof ApiHelper'.ts(2741)
index.d.ts(335, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<typeof ApiHelper>'
```

also, when I try to use any of the functions from the class, like

```
const Api = useContext(ApiContext)
Api.login()
```

I get an error `Property 'login' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiHelper'.`
even though function login runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first render your context initialized with:

```
// ApiContext is not an instance, there is no `ApiContext.login`
const ApiContext = createContext(Api);
```

So, either delete the `useApi` hook and use:

```
const ApiContext = createContext(new Api());
```

Or, remove the `Api` initialization.

```
const ApiContext = createContext();

// Will initialized through state
ApiContext?.login();
```

---

Side note: you really shouldn't use such class pattern with React, define helper functions and reuse them. Read about [design principles - Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html#composition).

Comment: Thanks, that actually fixed everything. I appreciate the site-note, I'll make sure to ready through.